# mysql if exists return the record value instead of regular output

Tags: mysql

I want a select that if/exists it returns the 'link' value instead of regular output.
so instead of '1' it returns the 'link'

Is that possible?

```
SELECT IF(
    EXISTS(
        SELECT link FROM modules WHERE module='license'
    ), 1, '/dashboard/'
)
```

Comment: What if there are multiple license modules with different link values? How do you determine which link is the correct one? Also, the accepted solution computes the max value, which is bad for performance (see the explanation in my answer).

Comment: @LajosArpad *...the max value, which is bad for performance* this only shows that you lack basic knowledge. MAX() is applied after the WHERE clause which filters the table, so it operates on the remaining row(s).

Comment: @forpas good luck computing the max value if there are 100 000 000 records which have their module being license and link not being null. You might have a nice lunch break while you wait for the result.

Comment: @LajosArpad where does the number 100000000 come from? Did you invent it? If the OP wanted 100000000 in the results then they would make that point.

Comment: @forpas the 100 000 000 comes from a question a developer should always ask himself/herself when coding: "**what problems may arise with this code and how serious they could be?**". Remember that even if the result set is small now, it could grow over time and future visitors having quite similar questions might have larger databases. I deal with very large databases and your approach is a no-no in many scenarios. So, when we teach query writing to enthusiasts, we should provide them a superior answer rather than an inferior one. I acknowledge that your solution looks correct.

Comment: @forpas but "correct" is not always enough.

Comment: @LajosArpad everything that you mention is based on the assumption that the requirement is not as the OP described it.

Comment: @forpas no, I do not assume that the requirement is different. My answer solves the requirement, but handles edge-cases as well.

Comment: @LajosArpad handling non-existing edge cases does not make a solution better.

Comment: @forpas so you assume that the edge-cases are not existent for the asker, will be non-existent for the asker and will be non-existent for future visitors. Also, you assume that the edge-case will be non-existent for the asker when applying your approach in a similar, but different use-case.

Comment: @LajosArpad my assumptions are based on the requirement as it is described in the question. Your assumptions are based on non-existing requirements.

Comment: @forpas to clarify: writing a code that is at least as good as yours and handles edge-cases as well is superior. Do you claim that if the scenario I have presented would arise then there would be no performance issues?

Comment: @LajosArpad read the OP's comment under my answer and I hope that this is enough.

Comment: @forpas again: do you claim that if there were 100 000 000 records after the filter, your solution would be performant?

Comment: @LajosArpad please stop. There are no 100 000 000 records. This has been clarified by the OP.

Comment: @forpas so you do not make that claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation with `MAX()` (or `MIN()`):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(link), '/dashboard/') link
FROM modules 
WHERE module = 'license';
```

If that specific `link` does not exist in `modules` then `MAX()` will return `null` in which case `COALESCE()` will return `'/dashboard/'`.

Comment: While this solution is correct, there are some problems: 1. You compute `MAX` which is unnecessary if only the existence of a single match is interesting, which is bad for performance. 2. If there could be more matches than a singe one and you need to get them all (this does not seem to be true now, but can become a reality), then doing an aggregation on the whole table will yield a single result. What if two records exist whose link is not null and module is license? Is it correct to choose the maximum? The asker may know the answer to this one.

Comment: @LajosArpad 1. I use MAX() because I want the query to return exactly 1 row because this  is the requirement. Also MAX() is applied **after** the WHERE clause which means that it does **not** operate on the whole table so it is **not** bad for performance 2. the OP uses EXISTS in their code which means that they are interested in the existence of that link which also means that it should be unique.

Comment: So, what if there are 1 000 000 records which have their module as 'license' and link not being null? What if there are 10 000 000 records? You can return a single record using the limit keyword. No need to shoot a sparrow with a cannon. I know that the op uses the exists keyword, but the op needs the link value. If there are multiple links matching the criteria, how do we know that a single one is needed? Also, if a single one is needed, then how do we know that in case of duplicates the maximum value is correct?

Comment: @LajosArpad your *What if...* does not make sense. You asked the OP a question in the comments. Wait for the answer.

Comment: @forpas my what if makes absolute sense. The answer is meant to provide a solution to the problem and help future visitors. Assuming that your assumptions that 1. There are not many results in the where and 2. a single record is interesting may or may not be correct in this scenario, but over the years it is likely to be incorrect for future visitors of this question. It is better to write decent code in the first place that covers the problems I have presented as well.

Comment: @forpas I sense that you have a feeling that I'm nitpicking. I am not. I just prefer codes that are of higher quality. Since your solution appears to be correct based on the question requirements, I definitely do not down-vote it. However, since it's below the quality standards I would expect from a code, I cannot upvote it either. If you add an explanation to your question specifying when your solution is adequate and when it should be avoided, then you have my upvote. If your answer suggests that in every possible case your solution is desirable, then that is preventing me from upvoting.

Comment: @forpas imagine the scenario when someone having a similar issue, but with lots of records resulting after the filter, by reading your answer, the person will have the impression that it is the best solution, especially since it is accepted. And then the person implements it and will have trouble optimizing it. Why do you prefer computing the maximum value instead of getting the first match only?

Comment: @LajosArpad then this would be a **different requirement** and that person would need a different solution which they would seek in a **different thread**. You could use many *what ifs* to extend the requirement further. Will you?

Comment: @forpas no, I do not assume that the requirement is different. My answer solves the requirement, but handles edge-cases as well.

Comment: in this case forpas was correct to answer the question as if. Small table search and only unique records. lajosArpad also the correct answer to my question. You're correct that the code is of higher quality and good for educational purposes and future searches. Getting the train to station is what i wanted both answers get it done. You two need to share the candy as friends

Comment: @DataConnect there are no hard feelings on my part. My comments were merely pointing out edge-cases. Forpas is a great developer and I'm sure that he deep down understands where I'm coming from. Nevertheless his answer is correct and your problem was solved. But please remember my points, they could help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

@forpas's solution is correct, but selecting `MAX(link)` can become slow if your table is large. We do not need to compute the maximum, since we are only interested in the existence of the `link` satisfying the condition.

This is a more complicated, but quicker solution:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.link, '/dashboard/')
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS foo
) t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT link 
    FROM modules 
    WHERE module='license' AND
          (NOT (link IS NULL))
    LIMIT 0, 1
) t2
ON 1 = 1
```

Explanation:

- we left join a dummy table with a generated relation that has the links you need if they exist
- `t` is a dummy table and serves the purpose to have a result even if `t2` is empty
- `t2` will have 0 records if there is no record meeting the criteria
- `t2` will have all the links you need if at least a record is meeting the criteria
- if there are multiple records meeting the criteria and you need them all, then you can remove the `LIMIT` clause from `t2`
- the `LIMIT` makes sure that your search stops when you find the first match instead of searching for a maximum